# How can I cause a "initscr" break with ncurses?

Tags: c, linux, reverse-engineering, ncurses

I know this is a weird question, but I want to get the "initscr" function error mentioned [by the doc](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcurses/initscr.html) (getting invalid pointer and an error message on  stderr) to test if a wrapper works properly.

But I don't find any information about that. I'm currently working with ncurses 6.2.

After few research, I have found that the invalid pointer is really a NULL, not just an empty one pointing on anywhere.

But I'm not able to break the function...

If someone know how to help me to break down this, feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: `the "initscr" error` What errror? `by the doc` What documentation? Could you post a link? `to break the function` What function? What exactly does "break" mean? You want to separate a function into pieces? You want to `return` from the function?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question. Is it fine ?

Comment: `Copyright © 1997 The Open Group` that's a bit old version :p So you want to "make" `initscr` error? inspect it's sources in ncurses and see what you can do. The [man initscr](https://man.archlinux.org/man/curs_initscr.3x.en) looks nicer. Also I think the doc you mentioned are clear: `Upon successful completion, initscr() returns a pointer to stdscr. Otherwise, it does not return`. On error `initscr()` is probably expected to call `abort()` on UNIXv2. So to what `getting invalid pointer and an error message on stderr` are you referring to?

Comment: The man page follows the behavior - `If errors occur, initscr writes an appropriate error message to standard error and exits` - "exits" as in calls `exit()`. And yes - in a jargon an "invalid pointer" could be understood as `NULL`, but an "invalid pointer" is indeed any pointer value that points nowhere, not only `NULL`.

Comment: I know that (I use the man too, but it's a bit hard to link it here... ;) ). I browse the sources, but `initscr` is not declared anywhere. I try to get the error (empty pointer and stderr message), to do so, I need to break something that cause the error. But I don't know what.

Comment: Ok - https://github.com/mirror/ncurses/blob/master/ncurses/base/lib_initscr.c#L72 here is initscr. You could "break" dynamic allocation - write your own `malloc` and return `NULL` inside `initscr`, so that `strdup` will fail.

Comment: Arf... I have made a grep in source files without seeing this one... Ok, it seems that I need to find a way to break `envdup`, now ?

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following program:

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool my_malloc_disabled;
void *malloc(size_t size) {
    if (my_malloc_disabled) {
        return NULL;
    }
    void *__libc_malloc(size_t);
    return __libc_malloc(size);
}
int main() {
    my_malloc_disabled = 1;
    initscr();
}
```

does:

```
$ gcc file.c -lcurses
$ ./a.out
Error opening allocating $TERM.
```

Comment: Thank you ! I'm new with C, I didn't know we can disable malloc ! :)

Comment: This code is specific to `glibc`. There is also [hooks for malloc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Hooks-for-Malloc.html) and they still work and are nice, but considered deprecated (mentioned in the man page). The `__libc_*` is the [internal `glibc` prefix](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/malloc/malloc.c#L5864) for all (most) standard functions, so you can overwrite them if you want.